# Ext JS: migrating GeoExt to v4... "Attempting to extend from a class which has not been loaded on the page"

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, geo, extjs3

I'm trying to migrate an Ext 3.3.1 application to Ext 4 (with the compatabiltiy layer, for now). I've run into some problems with GeoExt. Currently, it's breaking on line 99, saying "Attempting to extend from a class which has not been loaded on the page." **Line 99 is all of the code below.**

Any sugegstions or hints for how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
    return selectControl;
},featureSelected:function(evt){
    if(!this._selecting){
        var store=this.grid.store;
        var row=store.findBy(function(record,id){
            return record.data.feature==evt.feature;
        });
        if(row!=-1&&!this.isSelected(row)){
            this._selecting=true;
            this.selectRow(row,!this.singleSelect);
            this._selecting=false;
            this.grid.getView().focusRow(row);
        }
    }
},
featureUnselected:function(evt){
    if(!this._selecting){
        var store=this.grid.store;
        var row=store.findBy(function(record,id){
            return record.data.feature==evt.feature;
        });
        if(row!=-1&&this.isSelected(row)){
            this._selecting=true;
            this.deselectRow(row);
            this._selecting=false;
            this.grid.getView().focusRow(row);
        }
    }
},
rowSelected:function(model,row,record){
    var feature=record.data.feature;
    if(!this._selecting&&feature){
        var layers=this.getLayers();
        for(var i=0,len=layers.length;i<len;i++){
           if(layers[i].selectedFeatures.indexOf(feature)==-1){
               this._selecting=true;
               this.selectControl.select(feature);
               this._selecting=false;
               break;
            }
        }
    }
},
rowDeselected:function(model,row,record){
    var feature=record.data.feature;
    if(!this._selecting&&feature){
        var layers=this.getLayers();
        for(var i=0,len=layers.length;i<len;i++){
            if(layers[i].selectedFeatures.indexOf(feature)!=-1){
                this._selecting=true;
                this.selectControl.unselect(feature);
                this._selecting=false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
},
getLayers:function(){
    return this.selectControl.layers||[this.selectControl.layer];
}
};
GeoExt.grid.FeatureSelectionModel=Ext.extend(Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel,GeoExt.grid.FeatureSelectionModelMixin);
Ext.namespace("GeoExt","GeoExt.data");
GeoExt.data.LayerReader=function(meta,recordType){
    meta=meta||{};
    if(!(recordType instanceof Function)){
        recordType=GeoExt.data.LayerRecord.create(recordType||meta.fields||{});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this. Does it fix your problem?

> Ext.ux.form.AGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
> blabla: 'test'
> })
> Try using the new Ext.define. If you are using the dynamic loading, you need to use define with extend: 'someclass'. That way the dynamic loader will make sure to load the class you are extending first.
>
> Alternately you could just use ext-all.js and do it the old way.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-125402.html?s=cdae2bc4c55d9b9436b67d7a799addee

Comment: Thank you; this is helpful, but unfortunately does not solve the problem. With the compatability layer I can't use requires and without the compatability layer I get the initial error.